# How to change http code on symfony schema redirect

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm migrating an old application to Symfony, and for SEO reason need to keep part of it on HTTP and part on HTTPS.

I'am using `schemes` config key in `routing.yaml`:

```
route_name:
    path: ...
    schemes: [HTTP]
```

The problem I'm having is that Symfony redirects from HTTPS to HTTP via `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently`, but I would like it to redirect just temporarily because we are planning to fully switch to https in next year.

Is there a way to change the response code? Or is there a better way to keep part of the application on HTTP and part on HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested, so I looked into it. Unfortunately this seems a bit more difficult than what I would have expected.

The permanent redirections is hard coded, see:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/RedirectableUrlMatcher.php#L35

No problem, you just have to replace the matcher with your own... BUT NO. The matcher is not injected into the router, but created during the router's warmup.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php#L270

At least the `matcher_class` options seems to be what we are looking for. Unfortunately that is also hard coded:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml#L66

It looks like you will have create a custom matcher (with permanent => false), and redefine the router config with a compiler pass.

Unusually complicated, even by Symfony standards.